# Distance between parallel face or constraining width of cube

Tags: edit-mode

I'm using blender to create simple shapes I want to cut out of wood (not what Blender is for I know). The wood is 18mm thick so I created a cube that was also 18mm thick. The problem is that as I move certain vertices and faces, the 18mm isn't maintained.

The two faces are still parallel and I can drag them along their axes using the Normal option in Transformation alignment, but I've no way to drag them to exactly 18mm because their is nothing to snap to.. because the object is warped, I can't see width in the transform box either. Likewise, the measure tool doesn't work because again, there's no appropriate snap point.

Below is one example shape. The measure shows the two faces that need to be 18mm apart. But, because the edges that the measure is snapped to are actually bevelled, this is not acurately giving the actually perpendicular/parallel distance between the two faces.

This was a 18mm cube where the face at the lower left of the image has been dragged downward to snap to another object in the scene. Doing this throws off the 18mm. I could try rotating the cube instead, but trying to align it this way, rather than dragging faces/edges/vertices is just going to be insanely difficult.

[image]

and this is the final intended shape of the whole thing. How do I keep the wood at 18mm? :/

[image]

Comment: Just so as to be able to give a fitting example, is your final object a regular pentagon? Could you give radii, measurements in elevation? Which length do you want to be 18mm?